# How to publish a library that have multiple child libraries in mavenLocal?

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, java-11

> I am trying to publish my library which has 8 inner projects, But the problem is when i publish the library to maven local with the below code, only the parent library code is accessible not the child.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
publishing {
   publications {
    // Creates a Maven publication called "release".
    release(MavenPublication) {
        // Applies the component for the release build variant.

        // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
        groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
        artifactId = 'final'
        version = '1.3.8'
        artifact(sourceJar)
        artifact bundleReleaseAar
    }

}
}
```

}